# How to render a new page while using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here's [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-gauss-v9w05?file=/src/index.js:0-231)
for react-router-shoe-store-app which does not work perfectly.
when i click on each shoe it is not render a new page instead of this it changes the url but not change the whole dom, just change on right and bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with minor issues. You need `Switch` instead of `Routes` and `component` prop instead of `element` prop. Made the following changes and got your project running on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-montalcini-cgl47?file=/src/App.js).

You need to change your App.js to this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Home } from "./Components/Home/Home";
import { ShoesBrandLaunch } from "./Components/ShoeDetails/ShoesBrandLaunch";
import { ShoeLaunch } from "./Components/ShoeDetails/ShoeLaunch";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/nike" component={ShoesBrandLaunch}>
          <Route path=":slug" component={ShoeLaunch} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question,

Comment: i have uploaded my package,json above, i have v6 of react-router-dom

Comment: i think you have not seen all the files and folders in Component folder, there is some links in the App bar and the problem is there in nesting routes,  second there is an error for Switch and Outlet in my vs code and chrome browser, it shows me ** Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.**

Comment: This fixes the question, If you see my sandbox you can import the Switch. If this answers the question make sure to accept it. If not, hope you will get the answer. If you have another question, you can ask another one. Cheers

Comment: Check this out for nested routes: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-shoe-store-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```